# Flag a line of code in Jupyter for later review

Tags: python, optimization, jupyter

Is there a way to "flag" a line of code in Jupyter to remind me to review it later?

I find myself working on optimization iteratively, one section at a time. But often, I want to leave one line of code that's working and then get some kind of reminder to come back to it later.

Is there a good way to do this either via Jupyter or Python?

Comment: Most people put a comment above the line, starting with `# TODO: ...`.

Comment: Kind of like a hashtag, that's easily searchable?

Comment: You can put or call it a hashtag if you so want, but the hash symbol is just the comment indicator (and there is actually a space after it, for readability). And TODO is an obvious word to search for. It also stands out (hence the capitlisation), so that when glancing over the code, it is immediately obvious that there's still something that needs to be done (another example is `# FIXME: ...`).